# Are any maps for sale at Jeju International Airport?

Tags: south-korea, maps, cju

I am travelling to Jeju, South Korea soon, and I have been [unable to find a proper map so far](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5208/566).  Lacking a topographic map (that I would strongly prefer), at the very least I would need some kind of road map.  All I have now is printouts from Google Maps and Openstreetmap, but A4 is far from ideal.  Are any maps for sale at Jeju International Airport?

Hangul is fine, biscriptual Hangul/Latin is preferrable.

Answer (score 4):

I think they have various types of map available at the airport and tourists information centers near the attraction you want to go.

I guess you only want a topographic map for hiking, not for researching, so accuracy is not that important. The Korean government has this weird law where they forbid any detailed map data to be stored on servers outside Korea (technically they are still at war, but didn't they know North Korea have computers that can connect to the South Korean internet too?). As a consequence, Google was unable to provide a quality map in Korea for years. You can use [Naver map](http://map.naver.com/) instead (a big Korean search portal).

[Link to map for Jeju](http://me2.do/xOMq8xDC)

You can see from the above link that they have map for hiking trails (dark green) and elevation lines every 50 meters if you zoom in close enough. If you are not too keen on using a paper map and money is not a problem I would recommend you rent a phone with a data plan after you get off the airport, then download the Naver map app and have this map always with you. Korea is a very connected country and you can expect reception everywhere you go (Yes, islands included)

Comment: Do you mean I count rent a phone including both hardware and software, at the airport?

Comment: Yes, everything you need for about $9 a day. Read more [about the rates](http://www.skroaming.com/phone/phone_rental.asp). They have [a desk at Jeju airport](http://www.skroaming.com/customer/center.asp) (I picked SK as an example, the other big carriers are KT and LG, you can search for them too)